# What is the name of this pointed drill bit (used here for MDF)?

Tags: drill-bit

This long, pointed, gradually wider drill bit from this
[video](https://youtu.be/lpyPxrXTbOA?t=38) seems like an even better method to drill clean holes in MDF than the more common recommendation for brad-tipped drill bits.

What is the name of this drill bit?

[image: drill bit for MDF]

**Confirmation** (following crip659's answer):

To my eye this doesn't look like a spade bit. It looks like it has a peculiar profile. Can you confirm that this is indeed simply a spade bit, and perhaps comment whether a spade bit or a brad-tipped bit is better for MDF?

[image: spade drill bit]

Comment: Your left-hand sketch isn't quite right. Not all spade bits have shoulder points, but no common ones are tapered at such a long angle.

Comment: @isherwood That's a best-effort to draw from a moving object in a less-than-very-well-lit and focused video. Aside from that, and after a bit more image-googling, might the drill bit be a taper-point drill bit rather than a spade bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit sides look straight and parallel to me. There's a little light trickery happening, and the debris doesn't help, but I think it's a common 3/8" spade bit.

The side barbs are designed to cut through without blowout *if light pressure is used to finish*. No need to go inverted with good technique.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A spade bit.  Works more like a spinning chisel, with a pointy centre and flat side wings.